# Program with smallest possible memory footprint (on Linux)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I am looking for a program that does the following things:

1. Waits indefinitely, aka does not quit by itself when called with `./prog &`
2. Has the **smallest possible memory footprint** while running, as measured by, say, the `pmap` tool, program and `[stack]` fields.

This question isn't purely academic, I'm working on a [memory scanner](https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem) and I need a minimal example to work with.

The smallest I could come up with (in pure C) is:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm sure this can be dwarfed with some assembly/compiler/C arcane magic, as this one eats over 180 KB of program+stack.

Comment: Actually, you want linker magic, with a custom linker script to shrink all the memory spaces as much as possible.

Comment: `#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return pause();
}` will be *marginally* smaller ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser : I really don't think that source size will affect runtime size.

Comment: as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams stated linker script + linker options - reduce all segments to the absolute minimum. Stack and heap settings as well. You need to link without the standard library, remove all symbols like errno, en with while(1) insteed of pause etc.

Comment: PScompile with -nostdlib. You may end up with no bootstrap code then void _start() {while(1);} as aa program startup point.

Comment: @PeterJ Using `while(1)` makes no difference. I'd be glad if I could have some googlable keywords, as looking for how to reduce stack size returned only Windows-only answers.

Comment: find your lnker script. It is common for gnu tools.

Comment: Since you ignore the command line arguments, you could (should) use `int main(void)` — not that it will affect the size of the program.  If you're going to shrink that, you'll need to use assembler to avoid the overheads of the startup code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code-golf questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RossRidge For anybody wondering, code golf is on topic on [codegolf.SE].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this program:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

     .text
     .globl _start
     .type _start,@function
_start:
     mov $SYS_pause,%eax
     syscall # pause();
     ud2     # crash if pause() returns (should not happen)
```

Save in a file named `pause.S` (capital S) and assemble and link like this:

```
cc -c pause.S
ld -o pause pause.o
```

This shows as consuming one page of memory on my machine. This page is probably one page of stack space, as the text segment is mapped from the binary and thus does not consume RAM.

Comment: This definitely answers my question as stated, thanks, but now it's too much for my actual purpose, as I have no regions to scan. Is there an easy way to allocate just a bit? I can ask another question if needed.

Comment: @12345ieee Would you kindly make up your mind? Every program that uses dynamic linking and the libc is going to have at least as much memory usage as the one you gave due to the memory used by the dynamic linker and the initialization of the C runtime. Linking statically might reduce that by a little bit (but not much). If you write a program with neither, it's going to use as much memory as you use in your program, which is just about nothing in case of the program I provided. It's a bit hard to make a program that consumes significantly more memory than this one but less than a C program.

Comment: @12345ieee Is a program acceptable that just increments a counter (stored in RAM) every second?

Comment: Linux puts various things on the stack, like the argument list even if empty, before starting the program, so you're using at least one page of stack.

Comment: @RossRidge Hm... then that page was the stack page and the text page was not accounted for as it is mapped from the binary.

Comment: @fuz , I'm sorry for basically changing my mind. I'm accepting this answer, as it solves the question as stated and will be useful to google-nauts. I'll ask a better question later for myself.

Comment: @12345ieee Very good! If I'm still around, I am going to try and answer that one, too.

Comment: You realize that (on common architectures) for the cpu to execute the code, it must be in RAM? The fact that it's "mapped" just means the OS will fetch it from disk as needed, but then it is going to be in RAM... As to whether that's accounted as using memory or not, is a different matter.

Comment: @Jester What I mean is that because the page is mapped, it doesn't count towards “residual” field in the RAM consumption statistics.